# Fflush on a file

Tags: c

Having simple code from a [cplusplus.com site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/)

```
#include <stdio.h>

char mybuffer[80];

int main() {
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen("example.txt","r+");
    if (pFile == NULL)
        perror("Error opening file");
    else {
        fputs("test",pFile);
        fflush(pFile);    // flushing or repositioning required
        fgets(mybuffer, 80, pFile);
        puts(mybuffer);
        fclose(pFile);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering what `fflush` really does in case of `file` as its argument like in the above code because the result is the same with and without the `fflush(pFile)` line  - en empty buffer (nothing on the output).

PS: I'm running the code on Linux gcc (6.3.0)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194790/discussion-on-question-by-daros-fflush-on-a-file).

Comment: @Daros: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 5):

From the C18 Standard:

> **7.21.5.3 the `fopen` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #nclude <stdio.h>
> FILE *fopen(const char * restrict filename,
>             const char * restrict mode);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> ...
>
> 7 When a file is opened with update mode (`+` as the second or third character in the above list of `mode` argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file. Opening (or creating) a text file with update mode may instead open (or create) a binary stream in some implementations.

Here are the steps performed by the posted code

- the file **example.txt** is opened in read and update mode.
- 4 bytes (`text`) are written to the file, overwriting the first 4 bytes of the file.
- the stream buffer is flushed with `fflush()`, allowing a mode change from writing to reading. This is what the comment refers to: `// flushing or repositioning required`
- the program switches to read mode without a position change and tries to read up to 79 bytes from position 4 in the file, stopping at a newline. If no bytes can be read, `NULL` is returned.
- this line is output to standard output. Note however that if the file contained 4 bytes or less, `fgets(mybuffer, 80, pFile)` fails and returns `NULL`, leaving the array `mybuffer` in an undetermined state, causing `puts(mybuffer);` to have undefined behavior.
- the file is closed

Comment: *Here* being slightly east of Paris... I did not know you could localise SO this way: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/196880/sergeya

Comment: @chqrlie Thx for detailed answer:-) but can You explain me  `Note however that if the file contained 4 bytes or less, fgets(mybuffer, 80, pFile) fails`?

Comment: @chqrlie Can You answer my last question please?

Comment: @chqrlie it is a separate profile on ru.stackoverflow.com Actually, I am significantly **west** of Paris nowadays :)

Comment: @chqrlie Where did you find the C18 standard?

Comment: @Broman: C18 is the latest revision of the C Standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C18_(C_standard_revision)  - The latest draft available free of charge, N2176, is here: https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf

Comment: @chqrlie Ah, ok. Thanks. I usually go to https://port70.net/~nsz/c/ but they only have up to C11

Comment: @Broman: the pdf files are on the working group are now password protected! Such  a backwards move against common sense when C++, java, javascript and all recent languages are completely open! What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

`fflush()` normally isn't needed  when you're reading and writing the same `stdio` stream. `fputs()` and `fgets()` both access the same I/O buffer, so flushing isn't usually necessary in this case.

There are some restrictions, though. Even though the same buffer is used, you have to do something to synchronize between writing and reading. This can be `fflush()`, but it will also synchronize if you use `fseek()`. And if you want to read what you just wrote, you have to use `fseek()` to move back to the place where you started writing; that will synchronize without the need for `fflush()`.

But `fflush()` is really needed if some *other* process tries to read the file while this process is writing it. You need to call `fflush()` to force the data from your I/O buffer to the actual file, so the other process will see the changes.

Comment: If you have a file opened in update mode, and write to it, you have to use one of a number of functions including `fflush()` to be able to then read from it. See [cppreference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).

Comment: This is flat out wrong. See my duplicate or cppreference, or another answer.

Comment: I'm afraid your explanation is inadequate. `fflush()` is one of the ways to allow switching from writing to reading mode. `fseek(pFile, 0L, SEEK_CUR)` would have had the same effect. Furthermore, `fflush()` may not suffice for other processes to see the actual file contents, `fclose()` might be needed for some file systems and/or operating systems.

Comment: @SergeyA The first line of the accepted answer of your duplicate says **A single file stream has a single buffer.**

Comment: @Barmar that is true. But your conclusion ("flushing isn't necessary in this case") is wrong.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain that using `fseek()` to go back to where you started writing will synchronize reading and writing as well.